# Objects are getting expired from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using a CloudFront distribution with Minimum, Default, Maximum TTL as 31536000. The origin never updates the resources (only JPEG images) so there'll be no problems with invalidation

But the object is expiring from cloudfront every 4-6 hours or so. I verified `X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront`. Response headers from my origin server (EC2 Instance) are

```
Content-Length: 25158
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2016 05:55:57 GMT
Etag: "a9ff6462446825ce134199bf522368245449ba1e"
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Sep 2016 17:36:25 GMT
Server: TornadoServer/4.0.2
```

I am caching based on the query parameters.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're probably doing nothing wrong, although you may be making some assumptions about CloudFront's behavior.  I marked this as a duplicate of another question where I addressed some of these.  If you believe there is something that differentiates your issue, please elaborate. The conclusion that this question is a duplicate can be reconsidered if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. But 4-5 hours seems too less. It beats the purpose of having a cache

Comment: You mentioned that you are caching on query parameters, so that means request A and request B must have identical query strings for B to use the cached response from A.  I assume that you understand this, and this doesn't explain the problem. Is 4-6 hours consistent behavior?  What's the origin? Is is S3 or custom?  Have you enabled logging on the distribution?  Enable that, if not, then go find the logs for a hit and a subsequent miss, and verify whether they were served through the same CloudFront edge.

Comment: Yes I understand the limitations of query parameters. This behavior is consistent. The origion is a custom server on EC2, but will that matter ? Logging not yet, I'll be doing that soon. Even if I do, I can know the edge location that served the request. The header `X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront` indicates that cloudfront has evicted the object. And very nigh TTFB confirms it